# MYSQL IN Clause error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have used the below code in mysql query:

```
$all_PIDs=array();
foreach($pID as $p)
{
    $all_PIDs[]=$p->ID;
}
$AIDS=implode(',',$all_PIDs);
$table_tsk  = new Timesheets_Table_Tasks();
$select_tsk = $table_tsk->select()
            ->from($table_tsk, array
              (
                'Total'=>'SUM(timesheets_tasks.Time)',
                'Charged'=>'SUM(timesheets_tasks.Time_Charged)'
              ))
           ->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN ('.$AIDS.')')
            ;
```

But using the above code I am getting the following error:

> "An error has occured 
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1"

I have added a quotation mark(`"`) for `IN` clause. But the problem is the query only displays for the first `$AIDS` number. Could someone help me to clear the error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be specified as:

```
->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN (?)', $all_PIDs)
```

so you're passing an array of integers, not the comma-separated list of it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your suggestion. It displayed the wrong values.  As per your suggestion,the out put is 43:30 28:45. I have tried the hard coded query like :  ->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN(40,118,139)'). then the output is 51:30-34:30. So I think as per your suggestion the query only takes the first parameter(40)

Comment: @NewPHP: I have no idea what is `51:30-34:30`. "So I think as per your suggestion the query only takes the first parameter" --- it accepts whatever you pass in array. If the result is unexpected - check what you passed in `all_PIDs`

Comment: I mean it is the output. I just need to say the output is incorrect as per your suggestion. correct output is 51:30-34:30. But I am getting 43:30 28:45by using ->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN(?)',$AIDS).

Comment: @NewPHP: the output is incorrect per your query parameters, not by my answer. If you see the unexpected results - the issue is with *you* parameters not with this answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are not getting my point. Let me explain. $AIDS is 40,118,139 as per my query. I have tried to use ->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN(?)',$AIDS) and getting output as  43:30 28:45. Then I have tried ->where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN(40,118,139)') and getting output as 51:30-34:30. Hope they are the same query but different results

Comment: @NewPHP: please read my answer once again - I proposed to pass an array, not a string. As per your code it's `$all_PIDs`, not `$AIDS`. But anyway - your question was about incorrect syntax and I provided a solution. We don't know anything about the data you have and data you're passing.

Answer (score 0):

On your codes the quotes are not part of your MySQL query but only your PHP portion. DO this

```
$AIDS= "'".implode("','",$all_PIDs)."'";
```

And then

```
>where('timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN ('.$AIDS.')'
```

Comment: So it will be `timesheets_tasks.ProjectID IN ('1,2,3')`

Comment: @zerkms, Oh Yeah. Missed that. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @zerkms, I have fixed my error. Why are you still keeping the downvote? If you are not responsible for that vote I draw my comment.